# How can an android app work for a particular wifi ( internet) connection and not for other connections

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want that the android app should detect on which wifi is it connected to and work only in that premises only.

Comment: Ok. That can be done. Well to a certain extend .. What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a service that does a WifiRequester.requestSingleScan() (maybe 5 seconds or some other amount of time) and check if the BSSID of the network matches the one that you expect.